# Equivalence of a sequence list

Tags: coq

Where the definition of equivalence (`lequiv`) in Color's library: 
http://color.inria.fr/doc/CoLoR.Util.List.ListUtil.html

```
Require Import List.
Variable A : Type.
Definition lequiv (l1 l2: list A) : Prop := l1 [= l2 /\ l2 [= l1.
Infix "[=]" := lequiv (at level 70).
```

I would like to proof the lemma below. Here is my proof:

```
Lemma equiv_app_equiv: forall l1 l2 l3 : list A, l1 ++ l2 [=] l3 -> 
l1 [=] l3 /\ l2 [=] l3.
Proof.
unfold lequiv in |- *; simpl in |- *. intuition.
apply incl_appr_incl in H0. apply H0.

  A : Type
  l1 : list A
  l2 : list A
  l3 : list A
  H0 : l1 ++ l2 [=l3
  H1 : l3 [=l1 ++ l2
  ============================
   l3 [=l1
```

at this goal, I don't know how to go further, and I would like to know about the hypothesis `H1: l3 [= l1 ++ l2` can it rewrite to : `l3 [= l1 /\ l3 [= l2`? I do not find any proof about this case in the Coq's library (`List)`.

Could you please help me? do I lack something in my lemma? and is it provable? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather `In` is similar to `∈`, `[=` is similar to `⊂`, `[=]` is similar to `=`, and `++` is similar to `∪`.

It's not true that `A ∪ B = C → A = C ∧ B = C`.